# How to create an instance of Dart Polymer custom element in Dart code?

Tags: dart, polymer

There is [a guide](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/web-ui/spec.html#instantiation) on how to create Dart web-ui custom element in Dart code. There is also [sample code](https://github.com/dart-lang/web-ui/blob/master/test/data/input/component_created_in_code_test.html#L28) for this technique

Is there any example on how to create a Dart Polymer custom element from Dart code?
There is an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=12089) saying that a custom element cannot be created using `new Element.html()`.  But in web-ui there was no need to use `new Element.html()` at all.  Even though web-ui required writing a few lines of code, but at least it worked.  Is there a similar technique for creating Dart Polymer elements from Dart code?

Comment: I think this is a known issue. https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=12089

Comment: @user1848653 This is the third link in my post.  That issue is about creating an instance of a custom element using Element.html constructor.  I am interested if there is another alternative, similar to what could be done with web-ui (the second link in my post)

Comment: This is not possible yet. Please star the bug to be notified when there's a way to manually insert a custom element into the page.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is the example code:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

main() {
  querySelector('#add-here').children.add(new Element.tag('my-element'));
}
```

Notice the use of `new Element.tag('my-element')`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a neat little snippet they're using on the source code of [chromedeveditor](https://github.com/dart-lang/chromedeveditor), [e.g. here on Github](https://github.com/dart-lang/chromedeveditor/blob/master/widgets/example/spark_selector/example_ui.dart)

They use

```
factory ExampleUi() => new Element.tag('ExampleUi');
```

so that you could construct the element with:

```
new ExampleUi();
```